# Air- and light-sensitivity of phenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I've read that phenol should be stored under inert gas and protected from light.

- What reactions does phenol undergo during long-term storage in the presence of air and light?
- Is it really necessary to take such precautions when storing or handling phenol?
- How does the stability of solid phenol compare to that of phenol dissolved in, say, cyclohexane?

Comment: Phenol is oxidized to 1,4-Benzoquinone.

Answer (score 6):

Phenol slowly oxidizes on exposure to air and turns pink in color. At first, quinone (*p*-benzoquinone) is formed which again reacts with phenol to form a polymerized product phenoquinone which is red in color.

[image]

There has been research on the oxidation of phenol like wet-air oxidation and catalytic oxidation but those are out of scope.

Oxidation of phenol using light has been studied using UV/$\ce{H2O2}$/ozone system. [From this paper:](http://www.photobiology.com/IUPAC98/esplugas/phenol.html)

> The photolysis with 253.7 nm radiation practically does not degrade
> phenol. But the combination UV/ozone gave better results than the
> using only ozone. In the degradation of phenol using ozone there are
> two main reactions: the direct reaction of ozone with phenol and its
> products and the reaction of the hydroxyl radical generated. **Some
> intermediate products as benzoquinone, catechol and hydroquinone were
> detected during the degradation of phenol**.
>
> [image]

So, yes. Necessary precaution are taken such as phenol are kept at brown bottles.

[image]

I think solid phenol is less prone to oxidation due to air/light than liquid/azeotropic phenol because of $\ce{\pi}$ stacking, efficient packing of crystals and hydrogen bonding leading to stability.

Comment: "Google search" is **not** appropriate source attribution. BTW you shouldn't reveal urls containing info about your computer, as google urls tend to do.

Comment: @Mithoron I removed the Google image URL as per your suggestion. Apart from your suggestion, can you clarify the downvote (assumed you did the downvote)?

Comment: Same reason as the new post where you used this incorrect picture of not-an-adduct