# Phenoquinone vs benzoquinone

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, phenols

Are phenoquinone and benzoquinone the same thing? When I searched for the colour of benzoquinone I found that it's yellow. But when I searched oxidation of phenol in air. It states that it turns pink/red due to formation of phenoquinone. Also when aniline is oxidised with $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ quinone is formed (perhaps it is aniline black). Is it the same compound everywhere?

Comment: & what about aniline. It also forms quinone on oxidation but it is aniline black. It it the same case as a complex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Benzoquinone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzoquinone)($\ce{C6H4O2}$) is a [quinone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinone) with a single benzene ring. There are two types of benzoquinone:

1. 1,4-Benzoquinone also called *p*-benzoquinone. More common type of
   benzoquinone. It is the main product of oxidation of phenol.
2. 1,2-Benzoquinone also called *o*-benzoquinone. Less common type of benzoquinone.

[image: Benzoquinones]

Phenoquinone is a crystalline complex made of one quinone molecule and 2 phenol molecules. It is most likely formed from the polymerization of benzoquinone, hence the color change from yellow to reddish pink. See the mechanism below, taken from [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78556/air-and-light-sensitivity-of-phenol/78563#78563):

[image: Formation of phenoquinone]

It is formulated as $\ce{C6H4O2.2(C6H5OH)}$. See: http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0567740868002451

Comment: Such adducts are **not** hydrogen bound, but charge transfer complexes.

Comment: @Mithoron From ref 4 of my answer: "Different molecules in each complex are **connected by hydrogen bond between the hydroxyl bond and carbonyl bond** [...] In phenoquinone, one quinone molecule is placed between two phenol molecules to form a short complex chain. In spite of difference of complex chain, no significant difference was observed between complex due to short interatomic distance". I changed the "adduct" to "crystalline complex" but there is indeed a hydrogen bond between them.

Comment: What "ref 4"? I've seen this misconception earlier and it's quite obvious.

Comment: [Here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02773818808070678) is a bit about CT complexes of quinones and how they are related to color. Thing is h-bonds don't change color  to any significant extent and CT complexes *do*.

Comment: While then sure can be (even should be!) h-bonds between individual phenol-quinone complexes, color change cannot be attributed to them, but to change transfer between the rings stacked one over another.

Comment: Here's a simplified pic for adduct with hydroquinone https://files.askiitians.com/cdn1/images/2014825-141131979-6452-ox11e.gifpsig=AOvVaw1Sl6zvV-SZCgg45wC6d5m4&ust=1593453995357000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCNjv5O2MpeoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAU