# Resorcinol turned brown

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemical-formula

I stored resorcinol in a transparent plastic container with an airtight lid. There was some air captured inside the container too. After some days, it turned brown. please tell what happened to it?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, this is a almost a duplicate of a similar [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78556/air-and-light-sensitivity-of-phenol) on [phenols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenols). Resorcinol is [sensitive to light, if impure](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Resorcinol), and also, that reference states it's readily oxidized in the presence of water, especially in alkaline conditions.

See [Nilay Gosh's fine answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78556/air-and-light-sensitivity-of-phenol) for a more detailed explanation.